Value to be passed for @publisher - reinitialize pull subscription
I am checking for script to reinitialize a pull subscription and got it from the below link,
sp_reinitpullsubsription
But I am not able to figure out what is the value of @publisher which is to be passed.
From the below link, a value is being passed, but no where its definition is given.
Reinitialize pull subscription
Can anyone help?
Below is the script I am working on,
EXEC sp_reinitpullsubscription 
    @publisher = '',
    @publisher_db = 'AdventureWorks2014',
    @publication = 'AdvWorksProductTrans';


Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

It is the name of the database server that is publishing replication.
You could just hardcode it instead 'DBServer1' or whatever
